# Software to play video in intervals of different screens

Tags: windows-7, video, multiple-monitors

I have a presentation that includes a video. I have 3 60" TV's connected to a PC via HDMI. I want to play the video on first screen for say 20 seconds then show nothing on first screen while showing the video on second screen for 20 seconds and then show nothing on first and second screen and show video on third screen.

How would I go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple (slightly cheating) way would be to open the video in your favourite video editing software, and add large blank areas to the sides so that it's three screens wide, and then play it normally with the computer set to stretch it across all monitors. Or, if your system doesn't support that sort of stretching, create three separate videos, each of which contains the relevant third of the video, and a load of blankness. Then fullscreen them on the correct monitors, and just time when you click "play".

Comment: Without any masterful trickery, the easiest way is as stated, make your first video 20 seconds of content and 40 seconds of blank screen; your second video, 20 blank, 20 content, 20 blank; and your third video 40 seconds blank, and 20 seconds of content.